# oozie create a parameter with today date

Tags: date, oozie, oozie-coordinator

How can I create a parameter with today date of the format :

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

in oozie. I am passing this variable to hive script which is adding the partition for that date, I found the function to create [timestamp](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions) using :

```
<param>DATE=${wf:timestamp()}</param>
```

which should return output in the form :

```
(YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ). I.e.: 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45Z
```

but I am getting error :

```
No function is mapped to the name "wf:timestamp"
```

Also I only want `YYYY-MM-DD` from the timestamp and there is no substring function also which can give me first 10 chars of the string.

Answer (score 8):

For the basic EL function , you don't need to add `wf` so it should look like this

```
<param>DATE=${timestamp()}</param>
```

If you are using [coordinator](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html) , than use can simple add new param to wf.
it should look something like this

```
<action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${appPath}</app-path>
            <configuration>
                        <property>
                            <name>reportDate</name>
                            <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1,
                                'DAY'), "yyyy-MM-dd")}
                            </value>
                        </property>
              </configuration>
        </workflow>
</action>
```

Comment: i tried from coordinator  :      `<configuration>
        <property>
          <name>DATE</name>
          <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1, &#39;DAY&#39;), &quot;yyyy-MM-dd&quot;)}</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>`                                               I am using this date to add a parition in hive table, it adds the partition value as : `dt=$%7BDATE}`                          this is my hive command : `ALTER TABLE oozietest ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt="${DATE}") LOCATION "/user/hello/${DATE}"`

Comment: please add this to original question. have you tried my answer ?

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer. I don't think you can even have a workflow without a coordinator.

Comment: You can definitely have a workflow without a coordinator

Comment: i receive the below error while using coord:formatTime.
`No function is mapped to the name “coord:formatTime”`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704255/no-function-is-mapped-to-the-name-coordformattime

Comment: I'm getting following error on using ${timestamp()} for oozie SLA nominal time : E0803: IO error, E1004: Expression language evaluation error, Validation error :No function is mapped to the name "timestamp"                        Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Comment: @abhishekmahawar according to doc' this EL function is supported on all versions

Comment: that's what I saw, but for some reason it's not working

Comment: You can extract the date part of the timestamp using a regex. See my provided answer.

Comment: @Mzf maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but if providing -1 means it will be previous day, and per OP for today zero should be passed instead, right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a regex to extract the date from the timestamp() function:

`replaceAll(timestamp(), "(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})T\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z", "$1")`

For some reason timestamp() seemed to return date in the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmZ (not YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ as described), so that's why the regex is as above.

This should work for you, and not require a coordinator to be used.