# No function is mapped to the name "coord:formatTime"

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to get the current timestamp using the below in oozie:

```
<property>
 <name>date</name>
 <value>${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1,
                         'DAY'), "yyyy-MM-dd")}
  </value>
 </property>
```

My hive action is:

```
<script>/abc/test.hql</script>
 <param>DATE=${date}</param>
```

My Hive action fails saying:

```
EL_ERROR

No function is mapped to the name "coord:formatTime"
```

Any idea why it says so?I want my date as YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS

Comment: As you might guess, the `coord` NameSpace contains all EL function that are valid inside a **Coordinator** XML script only. And I would bet that you tried it inside a Workflow script *(but it's hard to know for sure because you did not care to show your script in context)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${coord:formatTime(coord:dateOffset(coord:nominalTime(), -1, 'DAY'), 'yyyyMMdd')}
```

This works for me. Which version of oozie do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the documentation for [coord:formatTime](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.8.2._coord:formatTimeString_ts_String_format_EL_Function_since_Oozie_2.3.2)

> 6.8.2. coord:formatTime(String ts, String format) EL Function (since Oozie 2.3.2)

So probably your Oozie version is lower than 2.3.2
Also it's important to pay attention for the xmlns version inside your coordinator xml

```
xmlns:coordinator="uri:oozie:coordinator:
```

Hope this help